# Failed to initialize tflite model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, yolov5, tflite

I trained a custom yolo5 model, and then converted it to tflite. Model works completely fine in both stages. I want to use this model in Flutter.

Right now I am using Google ML kit models, which works perfectly fine, but when I replace their model with my tflite file, it gives an error of

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(ObjectDetectionError,
> com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector.
> Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying
> NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images., null, null)

Any lead how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The yolo5 is not image classification model which is required by the [Custom models with ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models).

One way to solve this is to use a custom image classifier models with ML Kit tag from the [TFHub](https://tfhub.dev) .